# Transform conditional expression w/parenthesis to left to right evaluation w/o parenthesis

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Our framework has a simple expression language for business logic. Unfortunately this does not support parenthesis, nor does it support operator precedence. Instead, it uses left to right evaluation.

So the following expression:

```
a & b | c & d
```

will be evaluated as

```
((a & b) | c) & d
```

Can any conditional expression with parenthesis be transformed to an equivalent one with all parenthesis grouped from left to right?

More specifically: what would be the correct transformation of this formula?

```
(a & b) | (c & d)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to declare all subexpressions into variables and then creating a new expression consisting of those? So AB = (a & b), CD = (c & d), result = AB | CD?

Comment: @Richard: yes, that is possible, but that would cause a lot of overhead for the developer, so I was hoping to find a solution without that being necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not possible in general. To see why, let's put

```
p := a & b
```

and assume first that there exists `q` depending or `a,b,c,d` such that

```
p | (c & d) = q | c
```

Then `c` would imply `p | (c & d)` or `c -> (p | d)`. So `c -> p` or `c -> d`, both of which are impossible because `c` is not in `p` and `c`is not `d` (in general).

The same argument holds for `d` instead of `c`.

Now for `&` instead of `|`. Let's assume

```
p | (c & d) = q & c
```

for some `q`. In this case `c=false` would imply `p | (c & d) = false`, which means `p = false`. In other words `~c -> ~p` or `p -> c`, which is again impossible because `c` is not in `p`.

Same argument for `d` instead of `c`.

---

**SOME CLARIFICATIONS**

A formula written with left to right parenthesis such as `((a & b) | c) & d` has every of its subexpressions between parenthesis in the form:

```
(<expr>) & x
```

or

```
(<expr>) | x
```

where `<expr>` is recursively of the same aspect and `x` a Boolean variable. In the example above we have:

```
((a & b) | c) & d = (<expr>) & d
```

where

```
<expr> = (a & b) | c
```

is again of the same kind:

```
(a & b) | c = <expr> | c
```

with `<expr> = a & b`, and once again `a & b = <expr> & b`, this time with `<expr> = a`.

In other words, the kind of formulas you are looking for are all of these two types: `<expr> | x` or `<expr> & x`.

My claim is that general Boolean expressions cannot always be transformed to the desired way. If I was wrong then given any Boolean expression `p` the combination `p | (c & d)` could be rewritten. Let's see this is not possible. There are two cases:

```
p | (c & d) = <expr> & x
```

or

```
p | (c & d) = <expr> | x
```

Now put `q = <expr>` and read again my original explanation above to see that it is not possible to rewrite `p | (c & d)` in any of the two ways above. In particular the claim is true for `(a & b) | (c & d)`.

Comment: Sorry but I really can't follow your reasoning. Could you try to explain it in more basic terms?

Comment: @wvdz I've added some clarifications. Not sure they will be easier for you to follow, so let me know if I can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Your language, forcing ltr evaluation, can only perform operations between a previous expression, and one new variable.

You're parenthesized expression show this well:

```
((a & b) | c) & d
```

So you're asking if you can break up any expression to a smaller expression */+ one variable. This is impossible (in general) when mixing more than 1 expression of a certain precedence with another one with a different precedence, which is your example. From now on I use * for & and + for |.

If you want proof I'll try to explain Leandro (what I think he met), using a sketch proof. We prove assuming the negation, your expression can be written in the form you want, and suppose it ends with `d`. So one of:

```
A*d or B+d
```

where `A` and `B` could be any expression of the form you want. So, what do we know about `A` and `B`? suppose `A*d=ab+cd`. Let's try and break up the options (again) -

1. `A*d=ab+cd=1`, `d=0`. But if `d=0` then `A*d=0` and we have a contradiction, so this is impossible. (Note our new expression must hold for every possible option of `ab+cd`, and here it doesn't, so it's disqualified).

So, we try the second option:

2. `B+d=ab+cd=0`, `d`=1. Obviously no expression in `B` can save us here again, so we have another contradiction.

I leave it to you to do this assuming the expression ends in `a,b,c`. Same thing.

**BUT**, If you guys have to use your language and make complex evaluations there is a work around - perform all multiplication in the side, and then add. I'm assuming here you can have all your statements as ab+cd+ef+... and so forth. Along with negation this is a complete system, so you should be able to. You need to parse each product pair separately, with some function,so

```
A=ab,B=cd,C=ef....
```

and finally sum them:

```
A+B+C+D...
```

This is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation).

The infix expression "5 + ((1 + 2) × 4) − 3" can be written down like this in RPN:
5 1 2 + 4 × + 3 −